# Change displayed code chunk size when knit to Word

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

so I am knitting an R Markdown document to Word. In some places I have code chunks where I want to display the code. What I want to do is to make the font size of the chunk smaller.

I've read through standard references on this: [Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/word-template.html), tried adjusting [chunk options](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#text-output), plus the [R Studio](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_docx.html) article and even tried rummaging through Pandoc documentation.

The procedure seems to be to direct knitr to a template document, where you edit the Word styles. The problem is that code chunks seem to be comprised of many different Word styles: "CommentTok", "CommentVarTok", "NormalTok", "ConstantTok" i.e. everything that ends with "Tok" in the styles list. So the only way I can see of achieving this is to go through every single one (and there are a lot) and manually scale down the font size of each one.

But that seems like an unsatisfactory solution, especially if I want to later on change to a different font size or make a new template for another project, as it takes me a good 20 mins or so to go through every one and click "10pt" each time. So I am sure there must be a better solution - but I can't find anything anywhere. So can anyone help? Thanks!

**Edit:** a kind-of-reproducible example is simply to knit the default R Markdown doc to Word. Here's the markdown doc:

````
---
title: "Test1"
author: "Author"
date: "01/09/2021"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Save this file as e.g. "word_template1.rmd".

Then knit using `rmarkdown::render("word_template1.rmd")`. This is now the template document. Following the [R Studio](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_docx.html) article we can edit the styles in this document (in Word), and use this as a style template for other documents.

Here's an .rmd file that I want to knit to Word (below), let's save it as "testdoc.rmd". I have included some messing around in code chunks which is displayed in Word. If you knit this to Word `rmarkdown::render("testdoc.rmd")` you will see that the code chunks are composed of many different Word styles.

As mentioned above, I know that I can reduce the size of each individual style fairly easily, by changing the font size in "word_template1.docx". But since there are so many, this can be very time consuming. I am looking for global option to change the size of all code styles. Note that the `size` code chunk option doesn't seem to do anything in Word.

The desired outcome is to have all code chunk font styles in 10pt in Word, with a single command.

````
---
title: "Test2"
author: "Author"
date: "01/09/2021"
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: word_template1.docx
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Test chunk

```{r cars}
# here are a few operations - when output in Word this results in a mixture of styles
summary(cars)

# some dplyr operations
library(dplyr)
cars |>
  mutate(Newcol = speed*dist) |>
  filter(Newcol > 1500)

# creating a silly function
testfunc <- function(x){
  x > 15
}

# silly application of ifelse
ifelse(testfunc(cars$speed), "fast", "slow")
```
````

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I have included an example. It is hard to make it completely self-contained because it involves reading and writing, and manually editing styles in Word. Hopefully it can still help to illustrate the problem.